# Waveform Spikes

Tags: java, android

I'm making an Android Audio Recording app and I managed to make it with a waveform however I'm having a hard time to make a formula for the spike even when the surroundings is very quiet I'm getting a big spike in my waveform

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wvE.jpg)

**WaveformView Class**

```
public class WaveformView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private List<Float> amplitudes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<RectF> spikes = new ArrayList<>();
    private float radius = 6f;
    private float w = 9f;
    private float d = 6f;
    private float sw = 0f;
    private float sh = 400f;
    private int maxSpikes = 0;

    public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(244, 81, 30));
        sw = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        maxSpikes = (int) (sw / (w + d));
    }

    public void addAmplitude(float amp) {
        float norm = Math.min((int) (amp / 7), 400);
        amplitudes.add(norm);

        spikes.clear();
        List<Float> amps = new ArrayList<>(amplitudes.subList(Math.max(amplitudes.size() - maxSpikes, 0)
                , amplitudes.size()));
        for (int i = 0; i < amps.size(); i++) {
            float left = sw - i * (w + d);
            float top = sh/2 - amps.get(i)/2;
            float right = left + w;
            float bottom = top + amps.get(i);
            spikes.add(new RectF(right, top, left, bottom));
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (RectF spike : spikes) {
            canvas.drawRoundRect(spike, radius, radius, paint);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code how I call the Waveform once the recording started

```
        updateWaveformRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Check if mediaRecorder is still recording
                if (isRecording) {
                    // Ensure mediaRecorder is not null before getting max amplitude
                    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                        float maxAmplitudeFloat = (float) mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                        Log.d("Max Amplitude", String.valueOf(maxAmplitudeFloat));
                        waveformView.addAmplitude(maxAmplitudeFloat);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("MicFragment", "MediaRecorder is null");
                    }
                    // Schedule the next update after a delay
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); // Adjust the interval as needed
                }
            }
        };
```